# Unable to get Error message for HTTP request in Groovy through NiFi

Tags: java, groovy, apache-nifi

Below is the code which I have written in Groovy

```
def flowFile = session.get()

def postResult=''
def url = new URL("https://instrument-api.systems.uk.hsbc/gbm/ts/financial-instrument/v1/exchange-calendars?calendarCode=Hns")

HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection()
connection.setRequestMethod("GET")
//connection.setConnectTimeout(10000)
connection.connect()

rMsg = connection.getResponseMessage()
rCode= connection.getResponseCode()


flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'api_response_code', rCode.toString())
flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'api_response_message', rMsg)

if (rCode == 200) {
    flowFile = session.write(flowFile, {outputStream ->
    outputStream.write(connection.content.getBytes())
    } as OutputStreamCallback)
    connection.disconnect();
    session.transfer(flowFile,REL_SUCCESS)
} else {
    flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'api_response_error', connection.getErrorStream().toString())
    flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'api_response_message', connection.getInputStream())
    session.transfer(flowFile,REL_FAILURE)
}
```

When I run this via postman, it gives me 500 response code with the following in Body:

```
  "timestamp": "2021-01-15T10:47:54.938+0000",
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "message": "JwtTokenMissingException: No JWT token found in request headers",
  "path": "/xxx/xx/xxxxxxxxx/v1/exchange-caxxxxx"
}
```

But I am not able to get this body from my groovy script. If I try using `connection.getInputStream()` or `connection.content.getBytes()` it returns me null pointer exception.

Comment: 1) missing `if(!flowFile)return` after session.get. 2) when error http code returned you have to read content from getErrorStream()

Comment: why would you not just use invokeHttp processor?